# How to play a PCM data array with GStreamer

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I'm a newbie in `gstreamer` and I can simply use `gst-launch` to play a PCM file like this:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=output.pcm ! audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, 
channels=1, rate=16000 ! autoaudiosink
```

But In my application, what I got is a char array with PCM raw data. After google it, I know that I should use `appsrc` as a source, but the test code have no output at all.

Is there any example code can tell me how to play this char array which contains one channel 16K PCM raw data?

Here attached my test code:

```
std::ifstream file("output.pcm");
char data[22120];
file.read(data, 22120);
file.close();

std::cout << "read success";

GstElement *m_pipeline;
GstElement *m_source;
GMainLoop *m_loop;
GstBuffer *m_last_buffer;
GstElement *m_sink;
GstCaps *audioCaps;

gst_init(NULL, NULL);

audioCaps = gst_caps_new_simple("audio/x-raw", "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "S16LE", "rate", G_TYPE_INT, 16000,
                                "channels", G_TYPE_INT, 1, nullptr);

if (audioCaps == nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

m_source = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "source");
m_sink = gst_element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "sink");
m_pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("audio-pipeline");
m_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(m_pipeline), m_source, m_sink, NULL);
gst_element_link_many(m_source, m_sink, NULL);

gst_app_src_set_caps(GST_APP_SRC(m_source), audioCaps);

gst_caps_unref(audioCaps);

GstBuffer *buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL, 22120, NULL);
gst_buffer_fill(buffer, 0, data, 22120);
gst_app_src_push_buffer(GST_APP_SRC(m_source), buffer);

gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

g_main_loop_run(m_loop);

/* free resources */
gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
gst_object_unref(m_pipeline);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1. To create my own input test file:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc num-buffers=10 ! audio/x-raw, channels=1, rate=16000, format=S16LE ! filesink location=out.raw
```

Step 2. Here is a sample application:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsrc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    gst_init(NULL, NULL);

    GstElement* p = gst_parse_launch("appsrc name=src ! audio/x-raw, channels=1, rate=16000, format=S16LE ! autoaudiosink", NULL);
    GstElement* appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(p), "src");
    GstBus* bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(p));

    gst_element_set_state(p, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    FILE* fp = fopen("out.raw", "rb");

    for (int i  = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            gchar buf[2048];

            fread(buf, 2048, 1, fp);

            GstBuffer *buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL, 2048, NULL);
            gst_buffer_fill(buffer, 0, buf, 2048);
            gst_app_src_push_buffer(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), buffer);
    }
    gst_app_src_end_of_stream(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc));

    gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

    gst_element_set_state(p, GST_STATE_NULL);

    gst_object_unref(bus);
    gst_object_unref(appsrc);
    gst_object_unref(p);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

It simplifies a few things by using `gst_parse_launch()`. The complete pipeline creation and cap setting.

Further to make things simpler, the created sample file is 2048 bytes * 10 chunks. You don't need to know the original chunk size (as long as it is sample aligned - which is 2 bytes for 1 channel and 16 bit). I just didn't want to check for the file's EOF.

Basically, I think you should put the pipeline into PLAYING state before sending it any data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code you provided is really a very good example for starter like me!  Now I can successfully play pcm data base on your code:)